# How to send text using AlarmManager and broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am writing an app that takes in EditText data from the user and sets an alarm with the data collected using AlarmManager and then will send a text Using broadcast receiver. My small toast stating the alarm has been set works so i know the data is being gathered correctly but i never receive a text. What is happening?

Here is my main activity where I collect the data and set the alarm:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void scheduleAlarm(View V)
    {
        EditText timeField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            int time = Integer.parseInt(timeField.getText().toString());
        EditText dayField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            int day = Integer.parseInt(dayField.getText().toString());
        EditText monthField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(monthField.getText().toString());


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, ("Alarm scheduled for " + month + "/" + day + " at " + time + "pm"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }    

}
```

Here is my broadcast reciever:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {       
            String phoneNumberReciver="0000000000"; //my phone number usually entered here
            String message="Hi I will be there later, See You soon";
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumberReciver, null, message, null, null);

     }
}
```

I have also made sure to edit my manifest with these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>
```

but here is the whole xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bpa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bpa.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you debugged the AlarmReceiver? Set a alarm for a minute in the future, put a breakpoint in there and connect the debugger in eclipse. See if the method gets hit. Alternatively put some log statements in there. 
Then you can figure out if the problem is the broadcast receiver not being hit, or the SMSManager not sending the message.

Comment: I placed a breakpoint and ran through the code. (I added Toasts in the alarmReciever to see if it was running.... It looks like the method never got hit

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring the receiver in your manifest with a fully qualified package name:

```
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.AlarmReciever"/>
```

If that still doesn't work you may need to specify an action that your receiver handles, and then when you create the alarm intent, set the action to the intent. 
e.g:

```
       <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myapp.mybroadcast" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
intent.setAction("com.myapp.mybroadcast");
```